# Update a.zip file in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

I have uploaded a .zip archive into Google Drive. I have shared this .zip archive and I want to maintain the same link.

Can I add another file inside this .zip archive in Google Drive without uploading a new version of the .zip archive?

Comment: I do not think that it is possible. I tried this on my computer and all it did when I added a file to the pre-existing zip folder, it created another zip folder with the same name that had the new file in it. So in shorter words, NO. I hope that helps, -Adam

Comment: @ak11234: Google Drive now save files of the same name as new versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I just had success in doing this:

1. Download the ZIP file from Drive (or COPY it out of the Drive folder on your desktop) and decompress it into a folder.
2. Add the new file or update an existing file in the folder.
3. Compress the folder back into a ZIP file of the SAME name as downloaded.
4. Copy the newly created ZIP file BACK to the same location in your Google Drive folder and select Yes to any overwrite question messages.

This will overwrite the existing file and thus maintain the same file ID and thus sharing links is preserved!

Comment: If you re-upload does it upload the whole file again or only the updated parts hmm.. say my zip is 1gb

Comment: Thank you!!, your answer really saved me :)

Comment: This solution was a bit risky for me! I use this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PIm7o2DQ0jE